# Error running Spark 2.0 in Standalone: NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to run a simple Spark Streaming application in Standalone mode in Spark 2.0. I have one Ubuntu VM serving as a worker and my Windows host serving as a master.
To write the application I used the IntelliJ IDE, with maven dependencies.
Here is the issue: I start the master using:

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

Then, in the VM, I start the worker by using

```
start-slave.sh <spark://IP>
```

I then pass this master URL to my SparkStreaming Context, in IntelliJ, like this:

```
SparkConf sparkConfiguration= new SparkConf().setAppName("App1").setMaster("spark://IP")
```

The problem is this: when I run the application in IntelliJ, it successfully connects to the master, and I even see the application running, like so:

[image]

but this error appears: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp`

I'm using exactly the same version of scala in my Maven dependencies then the version that I am using in my VM and host, and have set the SCALA_HOME environment variable correctly

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
  </dependency>
```

I have no idea what else to do. Can someone help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you check the compatibility between the version of Scala you have installed on your system and the ones you are using in your maven build ?

Comment: @eliasah, yes, when I do `scala -version` this shows up `Scala code runner version 2.11.8`, so it's exactly the same that I am using in maven.

Comment: @manuelmourato were you able to resolve this issue? I'm encountering very similar issue.